# Multi module JHipster application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jhipster

Is it possible to have a multi module Maven project using JHipster?

At first sight seems not but I want to know if there's a way to share common classes like domain classes or repository classes among different web modules in my Project using Maven.

Suppose to have a Web module with an HTML GUI made with Thymeleaf (no React / Angular), a classic Backoffice.

Then I want to have another web module that expose some REST API that needs for the same domain classes and the existing repository layer.

At first It seems that I've have to duplicate these classes and code into another JHipster application but obviously It's not the best solution.

Without JHipster I create a multi module Maven project with 2 web modules (Backoffice + API) and a third module with these common classes packaged in a shared JAR included as dependency in the first two modules.

How (if It is possibile) can achive this with JHipster?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

JHipster won't be able to generate what you want, it's up to you manually refactor the generated project to suit your needs and it's not difficult because JHipster puts entity classes in `domain` package and repositories in `repository` package. You will then have to decide how you want to execute the Liquibase migrations.

You can generate only backend code using `--skip-client` option, see [command line options in doc](https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/#-command-line-options).

An alternative (if you are motivated) would be to write a [JHipster blueprint](https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-blueprint/#-creating-a-blueprint) to generate a project with the structure you want.

Comment: Correct, with JHipster you can create a "monolithic" or "microservices" architecture, both not generating projects with multiple modules. You can have a look at https://Bootify.io for creating a Spring Boot app with multi-module approach.